# Casting back void *

Tags: c

our course assignment is to build a tree index for a dictionary. The basic idea is to read (once) every word in alphabetical order, and to create a node for each letter of each node, provided this path doesn't already exists.

for exemple cab, cat, cats should become `(c (a (b) (t (s))))`; furthermore there should be a pointer to a translation, if the letter corresponds to the end of a word :

```
(c /no trans/ (a /no trans/ (b /taxi/) (t /feline/ (s /several felines/))))
```

Lastly, the linked list structure used is the basic C example :

```
struct node {
  void * data;
  node * next;
}
```

Is there any way to distinguish between `/feline/` and `(s /several felines/)` when casting back from void *, when the tree is used, and therefore add a translation or not, as needed, or is the only reasonable solution to add a field pointing to the translation to the linked list struct?

Comment: The `data` can be any pointer, including a pointer to a structure that contain the letter *and* the "translation".

Comment: In general, there is no such methods. But for particular circumstances you can e.g. allocate them from different arenas and then distinguish by pointer value (yep, ugly hack).

Comment: Ok thank you, Netch. So ugly that it would be too hard for me. I will add a field to the struct.... For curiosity's sake, how do you "allocate pointers from different arenas"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a field to the struct

```
struct node {
  void * data;
  node * next;
  char * translation;
}
```